# How to add syntaxhl plugin for tinyMce 4

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm forcing problems with installing syntaxhl plugin for tinyMCE 4.

https://github.com/RichGuk/syntaxhl

Of course I did all as told and copied to plugins folder and added syntaxhl in plugins (init function).

I found in Opera log that it can't find plugin.min.js , so I renamed editor_plugin.js to the given name, but it did not helped me.

Javascript is not my strong side, and I'd be very glad you explain me how to make it work

Comment: problem is the plugin you are talking about is made according to tinymce 3 older version ... tinymce 4 has changed a lot .. change editor_plugin.js to plugin.js and editor_plugin.min.js to plugin.min.js